# Bootstrap Modal no longer showing - Jquery in Site Master

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, typeerror, master-pages

I'm working on a .Net Web Pages site using Visual Studio 2015. Yes yes, I know. We use dinosaur technology here.

I had to go back and pull an older version of the code from TFS and now it appears I've broken something. Whenever I try to open a modal, I keep getting the error: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function

I've checked the network on Firefox devtools, and jquery is only loading once. I'm calling it on the Site Master page. It works fine in the production environment, and jquery gets called in the same order there as in my current local dev environment. So I don't think it's jquery (I've already read that article).

My production site is using bootstrap v4.6 and jquery v3.6. I've updated both in my solution through nuget.

What could this possibly be? Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer.

The issue was that jquery was loading within my datatables. When you download datatables, make sure it doesn't contain conflicting packages!